# How to set reading order in the accessibility pdf

Tags: xetex, accessibility, tagged-pdf

i am traying to create a accessible pdf with the help of pdfmanagement-testphase.sty and tagpdf.sty through xelatex, i need to set the reading order, for the below points,

1. when footnote link present, then reading order should read the
   footnote text then the following word after the link
2. when reference link present, then reading order should read the reference of the current citation after that the following word
3. Same for other citation like figures and tables

I created the pdf but footnote is reading at the end of page, is possible to fix this issue?

**MWE**

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{testphase=tagpdf,
pdfversion=1.7,
debug={%para=show,
log=v,uncompress},
uncompress,
activate=tagging,
}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tagpdf}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

This is the text\footnote{Foot note text} of testing.

Hope this is the example of \cite{ref1} and \cite{ref2}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{ref1} Ref Text One.

\bibitem{ref2} Ref Text Two.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well it is possible, but there isn't yet automatic code, so you will have to patch the commands to inject the right structure commands and switch the reading order.  Unrelated: but I strongly advise to use lualatex and not xelatex.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, i unaware the structure coding and command, how to do manual in the tex file, is any sample available to refer the coding?

Comment: tagpdf has a documentation and you should really read it. tagpdf is a part of an ongoing research and development project and not meant as a simple user package. If you use it you should understand that this requires that you put  some effort in it to understand and test the code.

Comment: btw: lualatex will give a different reading order, still not really the right one, but probably nearer to what you want.